# Remove first in a list only works first time

Tags: jquery

I have a list of results, and I want to pop the most recent one with a button click like this:

```
//clear most recent
$('#clear-most-recent').on('click', function () {
  $('#output').children().first().hide(800).done().remove();
});
```

but it only works the first time.  The error is `uncaught TypeError, ...is not a function`.  I'm guessing each subsequent call tries to access the now-removed element.

1. So the handler function isn't chucked out and re-created for each call, right?
2. How can I get the jquery set to update its' contents each time around?

link to project on jsbin (be warned, its ugly):
https://jsbin.com/lodobaj/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use callback function to remove:

```
$('#clear-most-recent').on('click', function () {
   $('#output').children().first().hide(800, function(){
     $(this).remove();
   });
});
```

Comment: This works, thanks.  Why doesn't it work with the promise `done()`?

Comment: `.done(cb)` well you have to put that remove call in the callback of `.done()` if you don't do then it will remove it before hiding.